# Angular2 Observable with RxJS no errors but event not fired

Tags: jquery, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm building a simple input type text with an Observable object linked to the keyup event on it.

I'm using Angular2 final ("@angular/core": "~2.1.1" with "rxjs": "5.0.2").

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(){
        var keyups = Observable.fromEvent($("#search"), "keyup");
        keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

When I press key, nothing appears on the console, so it seems that the event has not been fired or the observer is watching somewhere else.
What is missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to move the two lines which are in your constructor in the ngAfterViewInitMethod :

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
    `
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(){

    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var keyups = Observable.fromEvent($("#search"), "keyup");
        keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

But be carefull, you also need to keep a reference to your subscription to unsuscribe when your componenet will be deleted.

And I don't think that this is the "angular way" to perform what you want.

I think it is better to bind the "keyup" event of your input to a method of your component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input (keyup)="onKeyUpOnInput($event)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
    `
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(){

    }
    onKeyUpOnInput(data){
      console.log("Key up");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate! I've tried the first solution and it works! Totally agree with you about the fact that it is not the angular way to perform what I want but it's an example taken from an Udemy course of Angular2 to introduce rxjs :) But keeping those two lines in the constructor, is it possibile to make it work?

Comment: I don't think. On the constructor, your input element doesn't b exists yet.